# CustCode field in payflow link to generate report

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I have integrated paypal payflow link Api as below. I am trying to add a custom field CustCode in the orderform. I want display that CustCode along with other columns on report . I have added the field but it is not displaying on Report in paypal manager. Can somebody tell me if we can add that field in payflow link integration. If yes whats the error in my below code.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>my First Pay Pal</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="FOP" name="FOP" method="POST" action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com">
      <input type="hidden" id="LOGIN" name="LOGIN" value=''>
      <input type="hidden" id="PARTNER" name="PARTNER" value=''>
      <input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION" value="Order description here">
      <input type="text" name="AMOUNT" value="10.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="S">
      <input type="hidden" name="MODE" value="Test">
      <input type="hidden" name="NAME" value="test2">
      <input type="hidden" name="ADDRESS" value="test2 address">
      <input type="hidden" name="CITY" value="test city">
      <input type="hidden" name="STATE" value="test2 state">
      <input type="hidden" name="ZIP" value="test2 zip">
      <input type="hidden" name="COUNTRY" value="test2 country">
      <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="test2 country">
      <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT2" value="test2 country">
      <input type="hidden" name="CUSTCODE" value="">
      <input type="submit" value="Click Here to Purchase">
      </form>

     </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to use the COMMENT1 and COMMENT2 for the reporting purpose . As far as the "CUSTCODE" is concerned it is related to the L2 and L3 data which is processor dependent . I will advise you to use the variable "INVNUM" and "PONUM" for reporting purpose .

Comment: Thanks for Reply! can we use these field for payflow link or we need to use payflow pro if we want use these fields. Can we display these fields on report...

Comment: INVNUM IS DISPLAYING ON REPORT.BUT NOT ON TRANSCTION RECEIPT.

Comment: INVNUM will not be displayed on the receipt but it will be sent out  in the email to the customer .

Comment: yes,it did but can't we use custid or cust code in playflow link so that we can generate it on report usung playflow link.

Comment: thanks I went through the documentation of both link and pro so I think CustCode is not for link . I didn't check with pro so not sure about pro. But in payflow pro documentation section for  Addional custom report fields  I see CustCode field.